# Bottom overloaded by 248 pixels in flutter

Tags: android, html, ios, flutter, error-handling

Hi I am trying to create a search page. It is working fine for me. When I open the keyboard then it is giving me an error Bottom overloaded by 248 pixels. [This is how its shown on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVZH2.png)

I am confused on how to use the ScrollView Can anyone help to demonstrate?

---

this is my code:

```
Widget _usersListView() {
   return StreamBuilder<List<Contact>>(
     stream: DBService.instance.getUsersInDB(_searchText),
     builder: (_context, _snapshot) {
       var _usersData = _snapshot.data;
       if (_usersData != null) {
         _usersData.removeWhere((_contact) => _contact.id == _auth.user.uid);
       }
       return _snapshot.hasData
           ? Container(
               height: this.widget._height * 0.75,
               child: ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: _usersData.length,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int _index) {
                   var _userData = _usersData[_index];
                   var _currentTime = DateTime.now();
                   var _recepientID = _usersData[_index].id;
                   var _isUserActive = !_userData.lastseen.toDate().isBefore(
                         _currentTime.subtract(
                           Duration(hours: 1),
                         ),
                       );
                   return ListTile(
                     onTap: () {
                       DBService.instance.createOrGetConversartion(
                           _auth.user.uid, _recepientID,
                           (String _conversationID) {
                         NavigationService.instance.navigateToRoute(
                           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_context) {
                             return ConversationPage(
                                 _conversationID,
                                 _recepientID,
                                 _userData.name,
                                 _userData.image);
                           }),
                         );
                       });
                     },
                     title: Text(_userData.name),
                     leading: Container(
                       width: 50,
                       height: 50,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                         image: DecorationImage(
                           fit: BoxFit.cover,
                           image: NetworkImage(_userData.image),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     trailing: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                       children: <Widget>[
                         _isUserActive
                             ? Text(
                                 "Active Now",
                                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                               )
                             : Text(
                                 "Last Seen",
                                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                               ),
                         _isUserActive
                             ? Container(
                                 height: 10,
                                 width: 10,
                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                   color: Colors.green,
                                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                 ),
                               )
                             : Text(
                                 timeago.format(
                                   _userData.lastseen.toDate(),
                                 ),
                                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                               ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   );
                 },
               ),
             )
           : SpinKitWanderingCubes(
               color: Colors.blue,
               size: 50.0,
             );
      },
     );
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

warap your parent widget with Singlechildscrollview widget
for example:

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
     put other widgets here
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **Scaffold** property as following.

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can wrap whole body content inside Singlechildscrollview widget to avoid this issue .You can refer [Singlechildscrollview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) here